# Finding the immediate upper and lower of X

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a project, I have a table nearest_values as

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8450 |
| 2 | 8500 |
| 3 | 8550 |
| 4 | 8600 |
| 5 | 8650 |
| 6 | 8700 |

Given a value say 8555, I need to select rows 2 and 3 ie immediately below and above as below.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 8500 |
| 3 | 8550 |

another example for say value 8601 the selected rows should be 4 & 5.

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 8600 |
| 5 | 8650 |

Comment: Be kind enough to state your reasons for -ve vote.

Comment: This is weird, people giving -ve vote without having the courtesy to specify the reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a single row above and below value x in a table using SQL. Tested using Postgres 13.

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value INT
);

CREATE INDEX example_asc_idx ON example (value ASC);
CREATE INDEX example_desc_idx ON example (value DESC);

INSERT INTO example (id, value)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 8450),
  (DEFAULT, 8500),
  (DEFAULT, 8550),
  (DEFAULT, 8600),
  (DEFAULT, 8700);

WITH above AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM example
  WHERE value > 8555
  ORDER BY value ASC
  LIMIT 1
), below AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM example
  WHERE value < 8555
  ORDER BY value DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT *
FROM above
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM below
ORDER BY id;
```

Alternately:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE id IN ((
  SELECT id FROM example
  WHERE value > 8555
  ORDER BY value ASC
  LIMIT 1
),(
  SELECT id FROM example
  WHERE value < 8555
  ORDER BY value DESC
  LIMIT 1
))
ORDER BY id;
```

Result for `8555`

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 8550 |
| 4 | 8600 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/UnpfBjEub7yC76FXqCovS/0)